# How to mock an S3AFileSystem locally for testing spark.read.csv with pytest?

Tags: pyspark, pytest, amazon-sagemaker, moto

**What I'm trying to do**

I am attempting to unit test an equivalent of the following function, using pytest:

```
def read_s3_csv_into_spark_df(s3_uri, spark):
    df = spark.read.csv(
        s3_uri.replace("s3://", "s3a://")
    )
    return df
```

The test is defined as follows:

```
def test_load_csv(self, test_spark_session, tmpdir):
    # here I 'upload' a fake csv file using tmpdir fixture and moto's mock_s3 decorator
    
    # now that the fake csv file is uploaded to s3, I try read into spark df using my function
    baseline_df = read_s3_csv_into_spark_df(
        s3_uri="s3a://bucket/key/baseline.csv",
        spark=test_spark_session
    )
```

In the above test, the test_spark_session fixture used is defined as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_spark_session():
    test_spark_session = (
        SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
    )
    return test_spark_session
```

**The problem**

I am running `pytest` on a SageMaker notebook instance, using python 3.7, pytest 6.2.4, and pyspark 3.1.2. I am able to run other tests by creating the DataFrame using `test_spark_session.createDataFrame`, and then performing aggregations. So the local spark context is indeed working on the notebook instance with pytest.

However, when I attempt to read the csv file in the test I described above, I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.csv.
E  : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

How can I, without actually uploading any csv files to S3, test this function?

I have also tried providing the S3 uri using `s3://` instead of `s3a://`, but got a different, related error: `org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"`.

Comment: https://github.com/spulec/moto

Comment: why not just use file:// and test against your local FS until you are happy

Comment: @stevel because then I'm not exactly testing the application logic as it is implemented, would rather not make code changes

Comment: well, unit testing against and s3 store is (a) tricky to set up and (b) runs up costs. one limit is that because its hard to safely supply credentials to any CI toolchain, you can't automate testing so easily.  If you do want to talk to s3 on a local system, use the s3a connector *and set the classpath up*, as many other SO posting discuss